# How to scanf array char (char*) in c+++?

Tags: c++, scanf

I want to scanf char* in c++.

I must to use in program down.

This program is checks is the same y last letters are the same.

In the write from keybord char* can be ' ', (white characters)

How can I do it?

**Must I do it by loop for?**
???

Plz, help...

Thats, where I want to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int ile(char* a)
// some not interesting functions, which count how many vowels are in char*
char* koniec(char* a, int y)
// thats function, which is checks which are y last letters 
int main()
{
int x, y, wynik=0;
char* a;
char* b;
scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    // here I want to scanf a and b
    // but I don't know, how many elements I will heve to scanf
    if (ile(a)!=ile(b))
        continue;
    else
    {
                    // i want to know, is y last letters are the same in the a and b
        if (koniec(a, y)==koniec(b, y))
                wynik++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", wynik);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (m)allocate a buffer and pass its address as the pointer.

Comment: In C++? `std::string a; std::cin >> a;`

Comment: `using namespace std;` when no usage of `std` -> bad. Uninitialized variables -> bad.

Comment: I want it in c++, @Vladp

Comment: @H2CO3 - i'm sorry, i know, not iostream but stdio.h

Comment: @crahmstr i write using namespace std; involuntarily ;o

Comment: @ZosiaZamoyska *don't* You don't need it, ever. Get used to typing `std::`.

Comment: @crashmstr no, thanks, I prefer to write using namespace std; because every person I know write as me and someone learnt me to write like that.

Comment: @ZosiaZamoyska Learn something new, that is why you came here, right?

Comment: But, I want to know, how to write char* ...

Comment: How many elements do you want to read?  Is it a fixed number, is it controlled by another input, is there a termination condition?

Comment: I really don't want to write std:: i know that propably is better or easier, but sorry, it's too many work with this in programs, which i;m writing every day, sorry.

Comment: If only these functions had [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)...

Comment: @BenVoigt whats now? EDIT, i paste my all program, how to do what I want to do?

Comment: If you don't know how many characters to read, how should `scanf` know?  Is there a termination rule such as "stop at the first whitespace"?

Comment: You are definitely missing some `;` and at least one `{` and at least one `}`. This code will not compile.

Comment: Oh, and comparing `char *` with `==` will compare the pointers, not the contents. If you are going to write C-like code, you need to use `strcmp`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you don't use `scanf`. You also don't use `char*`, and you don't use `<stdio.h>`/`<cstdio>` for most of the time.

Propper C++ uses `operator<<` and `operator>>` for handling IO, `std::string`, instead of `char*`, and `cin` (from `<iostream>`) as the standard input. Google `C++ cin input`, and you'll find all of your problems got fixed :)

EDIT for the guys in the comments to the question:
The question is really basic, and was asked so many times it's boring - true. Still - report the OP is it's wrong, with a good reason, instead of whining. It'll be easier for everyone.

Comment: The same with '<stdio.h>' /'<cstdio>'
I use 'char*' in c++!

Comment: Using `std::scanf` may not be considered the best style, but there's no rule against it.  The C++ standardization committee put it in the Standard for a reason.  (And iostreams create far more problems than they solve -- Hopefully the next Standard has sanely layered APIs for I/O, buffering, and formatting/parsing)

Comment: The C++ standardization comitee puts into the standard nearly everything that's put in the C standard. @ZosiaZamoyska you can use everything you want. But it won't be propper C++. Hell - you can even use assembly commands. I told you what you should search the internet for - do it, or keep having problems and getting your questions downvoted :) The choice is yours here - noone's gonna make you write propper code if you don't want to.

Comment: @PawełStawarz i said, that in input can be something like 
1 2
asdf gh
alk kdj
There can be white characters, I can't use string

Comment: @ZosiaZamoyska you can. `getline` gets rid of white spaces. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/ You can also use a `stringstream`.